# Testing Partially Same HTTP Route With Angular and Cypress

Tags: angular, cypress

I'm trying to intercept a path with Cypress - "cars/".
Then I want to intercept "cars/details".

But it seems that I cannot.
It will always return the original value from the first intercept.

I'm searching for hours, but the best I could find was stubbing the Angular on Window, and ng was undefined.

Any idea?

Comment: please add your code that you tried.

Comment: I don't think the code is relevant here. It is a known issue. I just wonder if anyone has crossed a solution

Answer (score 1):

**Intercept ordering**

The intercepts are tested in a particular order, first one matching is used. The trick is to make the more specific one "cars/details" checked first.

The order of testing changed in a recent release of Cypress. Used to be they were checked in the order the intercepts were created, but that was reversed so that the stub could be modified in later tests.

Assuming you have the latest version of Cypress,

Ref [Interception lifecycle](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Interception-lifecycle)

> cy.intercept() routes are matched in reverse order of definition, except for routes which are defined with { middleware: true }, which always run first.

[image]

**Strategies**

- Make sure "cars/details" is the defined last.
- Define and use different intercepts in different tests.
- Add `{ middleware: true }` to "cars/details", it will always run first.
- Add `{ middleware: true }` to "cars/", use a functional route handler to check if url is actually "cars/details", if so skip response (checking will then pass to next intercept).

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use "path" instead of "url"